# Delay in hiding a button using Ng-Hide in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[image: Delay]]

There is some sort of a delay when I am using ng-hide/ng-show and it's bothering me very much. But when executed a similar in JS Fiddle it works fine. Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geektambrahm/Lvc0u55v/13488/)

Any reason why it's happening? And how can I fix it?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-show="isDisabled">HI</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-hide="isDisabled">BYE</button>
  <a ng-click='relink()'> Link me to my existing account</a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.name = 'Superhero';
     $scope.isDisabled = false;
     $scope.relink = function() {
        $scope.isDisabled = !$scope.isDisabled;
      }
    }
```

Comment: are you using ngAnimation or something??

Comment: can you check if any animation is applied to your page ?

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, i was using ng-animate. As I removed ng-animate it started working fine. Now I want to disable that ng-animate for that page alone. How can I do that cause I am using ng-animate elsewhere @SaEChowdary

Comment: @PrashanthVG check my answer to disable ngAnimate on only these buttons. May be it helps

Comment: @PrashanthVG oh thats great and next time before posting just try to search  it in SO first :-)

Comment: @SaEChowdary I searched for about 3 hours and I couldn't find any answer. That's why I asked. Thanks a lot, both of you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this css once

```
.btn.ng-animate { transition:0s none;
       -webkit-transition:0s none;
       animation: 0s none;
       -webkit-animation: 0s none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak
Use ngcloak directive
**I found below content from AngularJs documentation**
The directive can be applied to the  element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this 
CSS

```
.no-animate {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
   transition: none !important;
 }
```

Just add this class on elements you want to not animate in your application.
HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   Hello, {{name}}!
   <button class="btn btn-warning no-animate" ng-show="isDisabled">HI</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary no-animate" ng-hide="isDisabled">BYE</button>
   <a ng-click='relink()'> Link me to my existing account</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` or `ng-hide`:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-if="isDisabled">HI</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="!isDisabled">BYE</button>
  <a ng-click='relink()'> Link me to my existing account</a>
</div>
```

Comment: that doesn't makes any sense... You can use either one. In this case there will be not effect.